# Problema generando un numero pseudo aleatorio con rand

Tags: c++

Por exigencias del profesor tengo que usar la función rand() y srand() para generar números pseudoaleatorios. Soy consciente de que no es la mas eficiente/recomendable en la actualidad para este propósito pero este profesor es un poco "tradicional".

Para generar los números he usado esta función (hecha por mi):

```
int ej1(int l_superior, int l_inferior){
    //inicializamos la seed de rand
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % (l_superior - l_inferior + 1)+l_inferior;
}
```

La misma me genera los numeros de forma correcta, pero solo y exclusivamente durante una ejecución, es decir, si meto en un bucle dicha función únicamente generará un mismo número n veces.
Ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout <<ej1(6,1)<<", ";
    }
```

Tendra la salida: n, n, n, n, ...

Y necesitaría poder generar números distintos durante el tiempo de ejecución para otro ejercicio, es decir, tener una salida : n1, n2, n3, ...

Gracias de antemano y a ser posible no sean duros con este novatillo =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El generador de números aleatorios funciona así:

Cada vez que llamas a `rand`, la función lee un valor *semilla* que se encuentra en una variable a la cual tu no tienes acceso. Ese valor se utiliza para generar otro número diferente. Ese número diferente será el número aleatorio que tu obtendrás y será también la semilla del siguiente valor.

Para inicializar dicha semilla se hace uso de la función `srand`.

Es decir, si tu inicializas la semilla con un valor `X`, generas 10 números aleatorios, vuelves a inicializar la semilla con el mismo valor y generas otros 10 números, podrás observar que las dos secuencias son idénticas.

La función `time(NULL)` te devuelve una marca de tiempo en **segundos**, por lo que todas las llamada que hagas dentro de dicho segundo te devolverán exactamente el mismo valor.

Es decir, salvo que las llamadas a `rand()` se hiciesen en segundos diferentes, tu código generará `n` números idénticos porque la semilla pasa a ser la misma en todos los casos.

La solución es bien simple, llama a `srand` una **única vez** en todo el programa. Por ejemplo nada más empezar el mismo:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me solucionó el problema :)